# Check specific column in list for duplicates, skip null or empty values

Tags: c#, linq

I am checking particular column in list for duplicate values. List is originally from database and for some customers column KONSERNI is empty. So some of values in this column are null/empty = no value. Current code thinks that these null/empty are duplicates. How to skip nulls while performing linq query?

```
                var duplicatesKonserni = results.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(dr => dr.KONSERNI.Trim())
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                    .SelectMany(g => g)
                    .ToList();
```

I have tried :

```
                var duplicatesKonserni = results.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(dr => dr.KONSERNI.Trim())
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1 && g != null)
                    .SelectMany(g => g)
                    .ToList();
```

No error but result is the same as in first code provided. Nulls are still in outputted list?

---

**EDIT:**

Here is full code for testing: https://dotnetfiddle.net/saRl3G

Output should be:

```
{ NAME = Fiat, MODEL = Punto, NAMEB = 500, POSTADR = P4 }
{ NAME = BMW, MODEL = E64, NAMEB = SE0, POSTADR = P4 }
```

Not as it is now:

```
{ NAME = Fiat, MODEL = Punto, NAMEB = 500, POSTADR = P4 }
{ NAME = BMW, MODEL = E64, NAMEB = SE0, POSTADR = P4 }
{ NAME = LADA, MODEL = S23, NAMEB = S1D3, POSTADR =  }
{ NAME = Bugatti, MODEL = PO2, NAMEB = SQ4, POSTADR =  }
```

Comment: try to use `Where` before `GroupBy`

Comment: Also, attempt to call `Trim()` on `null` string can cause an exception, so you should use `.Where(dr => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.POSTADR))` before `GroupBy`, according to your dotnetfiddle sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing `.GrouBy()` before filtering `null` or empty values.

1. Filter all records where `POSTADR` of each element is not null or
   empty.
2. Apply `GroupBy()` records to check duplicate records based on
   `POSTADR`.
3. Again Filter to check `Count()` of each group is greater
   than 1 or not

Your Linq will look like,

```
 var duplicatesPOSTADR = list.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(g => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(g.POSTADR)) //Filter all records where POSTADR is not null or empty
         .GroupBy(dr => dr.POSTADR.Trim())                  //GroupBy POSTADR
         .Where(gr => gr.Count() > 1)                       //Check for duplicate records
         .SelectMany(g => g)                               //Select entire object
         .ToList();                                       //Convert to List
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vw5zIe)

Comment: Thank you for this! `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` worked, `IsNullOrEmpty` didn't.

Comment: I updated my answer even after your acceptance, I covered all scenarios motioned by @PavelAnikhouski. This will work without any errors